# Free Tools for Salesforce Data Backup

Tags: tools

I wanted to know the names of free tools that allow to save daily and automatically salesforce data via api (so that allow the daily backup of production salesforce data via api connection).
Thanks.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! We do not generally provide product suggestions, even for free ones. Questions like this tend to be subjective by nature and change over time, making them rather unsuitable for this site. You can read more about our guidelines in the [ask] page. However, we'd be more than happy to help you with any questions that do fall in our guidelines, so I hope you'll continue to come and visit. If you feel you can align your question with our guidelines, feel free to [edit] your question, and we'll be happy to answer as we can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check on [DailyExport.io](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FvL76UAF&tab=e) which provides automatic free daily backup of your Salesforce Data and Metadata.

- Review salesforce’s backup solution,  [Backup &
  Restore](https://www.salesforce.com/news/stories/salesforce-debuts-backup-and-restore-to-guard-business-data-against-mishaps-and-mayhem/) is a paid add-on and will automatically backup, as well
  as restore your data in the event of data loss.
- Check  [Best    practices to backup Salesforce data](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386692&type=1).

Below are few list of data backup tools(paid) available on AppExchange.

[GRAX](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FMtthUAD&tab=e) , [Spanning](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B51BgEAJ&tab=e) , [CloudAlly](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003JDGaEAO&tab=e) , [AvePoint](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3u00000Pv0faEAB&tab=e) , [OwnBackup](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000007p6RYEAY&tab=e), [Gearset](https://gearset.com/) etc., you can find many more on AppExchange.